# Prediction Interval formula for WLS regression

Tags: r, prediction-interval, weighted-regression, wls, weighted-variance

I have been unable to find a non-matrix notation formula to calculate prediction interval for a weighted least squares regression.  For OLS, I have

$$y = \hat y \pm t\times \sqrt{\left(\textrm{MSE}\times(1 + 1/n + (x-\bar x)^2/\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2)\right) }. $$

I even have the prediction interval values from R but cannot seem to reproduce them. The output from R includes SE.fit and residual.scale but I am not sure how to use them. Note that the weight factors are not normalized.  I have tried many things, including

y = yhat +/-t* SQRT(MSE*(1/WF + 1/(SUM WFi) + WF*(x-xwbar)^2/SUM(WFi*(xi-xwbar)^2)))

where WF is the weight factor estimated for x and MSE is the square of residual.scale from R. I also tried
y = yhat +/- t* SQRT(MSE + se.fit^2) using MSE and se.fit from the R output.

Nothing has reproduced the prediction intervals in the R output. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. This is a MathJax-enabled site. Please use this facility to typeset your mathematical expressions for better legibility. For a quick guide, check this Meta CV post: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated). I have tried to fix one. Also, it would be better if you specify the R output you are talking about.